# Why is this jQuery Slideshow not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a jquery slideshow for a website, I have only worked with jquery and javascript briefly (not really a web developer fan, I think its great and all but not my thing) I was following a tutorial to learn how to tie the code together and thought I had it put together. It is suppose to fade in and out according to the stack and all I am getting is a flicker.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slideshow Tester</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #slideshow{
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative:
        }
        .slide{
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    /*global $, jQuery, console, window*/
        (function ($){
            "use strict";
            var slideshow = (function (){
                var counter = 0;
                i,
                j,
                slides = $("#slideshow .slide"),
                slidesLen = slides.length - 1;
                for(i = 0, j = 9999; i & lt; slides.length; i +=j, j -= 1){
                    $(slides[i]).css("z-index", j);
                }
                return{
                    startSlideshow: function(){
                        window.setInterval(function(){
                            if (counter === 0){
                                slides.eq(counter).fadeOut();
                                counter += 1;
                            }
                            else if(counter === slidesLen){
                                counter = 0;
                                slides.eq().fadeIn(function(){
                                    slides.fadeIn();
                                });
                            }
                            else{
                                slides.eq().fadeOut();
                                counter+=1;
                                }
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    };
                }());
                slideshow.startSlideshow();
            }(jQuery));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "slider">
        <div id = "slideshow">
            <img class = "slide" src="img\DSC_0788.jpg" />
            <img class = "slide" src="img\facebook.jpg" />
            <img class = "slide" src="img\DSC_0788.jpg" />
            <img class = "slide" src="img\facebookGrey.jpg" />
            <img class = "slide" src="img\DSC_0788.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: offtopic but probably should use a more recent version of jquery

Comment: I just tried it again with the latest release and still only got a flicker, the problem with using the most updated version is that 2.0 is no longer compatible with IE 6 7 or 8 so I may run into future problems with management.

Comment: That was a just a suggestion as the more recent ones have bug fixes etc in them, it wasnt meant to fix the flicker. There are two latest versions the 2.x series and the 1.x series, the 1.x series still has support for the older browsers.

Comment: Thanks man, I tried it again ... something isn't right with the code somewhere it isn't rendering the fade in fade out and I can't figure out why, I saw on here somewhere someone said I needed to place my script at the bottom of the page and that didn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

You can not have JavaScript code inside of a script tag with an external source.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
    /*global $, jQuery, console, window*/
```

needs to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /*global $, jQuery, console, window*/
```

Comment: I tried it both ways just to be sure, I also tried using an updated version of JQuery just in case I tried both ways of running it also from a downloaded file and from the direct link I still only get a flicker when the page loads and no transition between pages.

Comment: Ah, you are running the script before the elements are rendered, hence why it does not work. Remove all of your script from the head and place it before the `</body>`

Comment: Just tried that, I still can't seem to get it to work, I am thinking it is in the fade function or the transition function...

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

close script properly...

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
     <script>
     /*global $, jQuery, console, window*/
       (function ($){
            "use strict";
     ..........
      </script>
```

And Put Both script just above

```
    <div class = "slider">
```

but below

```
 <body>
```

part instead of head section. And Keep style css as it is in head section. Also Check if there is any other version of external jquery scrip ...along with this 1.4.2 version...if it is...use noconflict()